# Unable to place new customer orders in admin backend

Tags: magento-1.7, error, customer, wishlist

Currently unable to place new customer orders in our magento store's admin backend via `Sales > Orders > Create New Order > Select customer from list`. The page doesn't fully load. See screenshot below:

[image]

When attempting to do so the following is recored in our server's error_log file.

> 2015/07/27 20:57:30 [error] 45314#0: *265562 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCustomerIdFieldName() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php on line 95" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.example.com, request: "POST /index.php/admin/sales_order_create/loadBlock/key/6b6b15a2f212013a5e09a87fc4915456/block/data?isAjax=true HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/sales_order_create/index/key/77cb0182ed34467e216b34c8d56e52ee/"

I'm also seeing the following error in my browsers console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) -http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/sales_order_create/loadBlock/key/54f74380de40f378caabe0adbdd6b4c3/block/data?isAjax=true

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please include Magento version

Comment: We are using version 1.7.0.2

Comment: did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: what exact php version is running there?